# Скрипт переключения звуковых устройств

Tags: ubuntu, bash, аудио

есть колонки и наушники, хочу забиндить клавишу для переключения между этими звуковыми устройствами. И хотелось бы без установки доп.пакетов и прочих программ, потому что все что нужно и так уже есть. Пишу

```
#!/bin/bash

# массив имен звук.устройств [1]
declare -a SINKS=(
    "<alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>"
    "<alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc...>"
)

# далее собираюсь опрашивать их состояния и складывать здесь
declare -a STATES

# выгребаю огромную портянку инфы по этим устройствам
# и грепаю её до обходимого минимума [2]
IFS=$'\n\t'
STATE=$(pacmd list-sinks | egrep "name:|state:")

# теперь разбираю то, что получилось и формирую массив STATES
for line in ${STATE[@]}; do
  # разбиваю строку на ключ-значение [3]
      key=$(echo $line | awk -F ': ' '{print $1}')
      value=$(echo $line | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}')

      if [ "$key" == "name" ]; then
            LAST_KEY="$value"
      fi

      if [ "$key" == "state" ]; then
    # на эту строку ругается [4]
            STATES[$LAST_KEY]=$value
      fi

done

echo $STATES
```

В результате получаю одну пустую строку. Мой мозг, привыкший к javascript, напрочь отказывается понимать эту писанину. Буду очень признателен тому, кто поможет.

**Состояние переменных**

[1] Тут вроде все хорошо

```
<alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo> <alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo>
```

[2] Тут тоже

```
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
state: SUSPENDED
name: <alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo>
state: SUSPENDED
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
state: RUNNING
```

[3] Все норм (echo "$key::$value")

```
name::<alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
state::SUSPENDED
name::<alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo>
state::SUSPENDED
name::<alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
state::RUNNING
```

[4] ошибка, вроде как из-за неё цикл прерывается

```
line 21: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже вам нужен ассоциативный массив, вместо обычного:

```
declare -A STATES
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее ваше решение. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п. Подробный и качественный ответ поможет гораздо большему количеству людей, столкнувшихся с подобной проблемой.